# Could you please help me break this sentence down?

Tags: grammar, meaning

日本の英語教育がゴミということに気づかされた。

I know the vocabulary but I don't understand what is "という" doing there. Also, I would like to know what form is 気づく using. I went through all my notes but couldn't find anything.

Finally, if it's not too much to ask, could you please correct my English if I got anything wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Related (regarding 気づかされる): https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/40730/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15157/9831

Comment: Questions about your English should probably be posted to the English Learners' Stack Exchange, but since you asked: Your question is well written and very easy to understand – in fact, it's clearer than some questions posted here by native speakers of English! However, there's a mistake in word order that you've made twice. It should be "I don't understand what という is doing there" and "I would like to know what form 気づく is using." (In that second sentence, though, "I would like to know what form 気づく is in" would actually be more idiomatic.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

気づかす： to make (someone) realize

気づかされた : I was made to realize

ことに気付かされた： I was made to realize the fact

日本の英語教育がゴミ**という**ことに気付かされた: I was made to realize the fact **that** English education in Japan is trash.

Because こと is a noun, you need some form to modify a noun to connect the clause that says 日本の英語教育がゴミ（だ）. Now, と as in という is a particle that indicates a quote, and いう is "to say" in a form that can modify a noun.

Comment: if the だ had been there, ie ゴミだということ, this would have been easy to understand. but since this だ has been omitted, i too was confused.  why may this だ be omitted like this?

Comment: Omission of だ is common especially in colloquial Japanese.